# Not able to configure EhCache for hibernate 4.1.1 as it throws " net/sf/ehcache/CacheException"

Tags: java, database, hibernate, caching, ehcache

```
<!--Cache Provider-->
     <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property> 
     <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property> 
    <!--The Query-level Cache-->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

These are the properties i defined in hibernate.cfg.xml. When I used the similar way in hibernate 3 versions it worked but in 4.1.1 hibernate it is throwing " net/sf/ehcache/CacheException". I have included hibernate-ehcache-4.1.1 jar also. I even tried adding the ehcache 2.8 jar. Still each addition adds to the list of errors. Please help me.

The stacktrace is below...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/ehcache/CacheException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:386)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:251)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2273)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2269)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1738)
at com.gau.dbaccess.HibernateUtilities.<clinit>(HibernateUtilities.java:31)
at com.gau.dbaccess.ComponentsDetailsAccess.resetOnlinePsdLockAfterServerStart(ComponentsDetailsAccess.java:3503)
at com.gau.controller.ApplicationContextController.contextInitialized(ApplicationContextController.java:132)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:657)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1637)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    ... 26 more
Jan 8, 2014 3:40:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 8, 2014 3:40:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal

Comment: Please post stacktrace.

Comment: In your `WEB-INF/lib` in your deployed app, can you see `ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are mixing hibernate3 and hibernate4 stuff.
Remove all old hibernate3 code and classes; if you are using spring use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` (check package, must be the hibernate4 one)

Comment: as you doubt the cache works perfectly in hibernate 3 as i tried for a sample application. but we have long before migrated to hibernate 4.1. So i think there is no mixup.